# Map of std::mutex: how to call emplace when constructor takes no arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

I have a `std::map<int, std::mutex>` and want to add an element. Since `std::mutex` is not movable, I need to go for `emplace`, right?

I am familiar with the `map.emplace(<key>, <constructorArgument>)` syntax, but how does this work, when the constructor takes no arguments?

Minimal test code including stuff that does not work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::mutex> mm;
//    mm[3] = std::mutex();
//    mm.emplace(3, std::mutex());
//    mm.emplace(3, {});
//    mm.emplace(3, ());
//    mm.emplace(3);

    std::cout << mm.size() << " elements" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the same question was yesterday: `mm.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(3), std::forward_as_tuple());`

Comment: @PiotrS.: Or just `mm[3];` if verbosity isn't your thing.